# How to deploy to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

The default tutorials of Azure explains how to create a project from scratch, and deploy it to Azure Cloud Service. I have got into unexpectable problem while trying to deploy existed project.

So, what I have is existed web solution of several projects stored in GIT. Inside solution there is a main project, which contains all relations and after building the folder of this project is ready for deployment to server.

The question is - how can I configure the project for Azure Deployment, and build a deployment package for it through the CLI tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time of researching, I've found a working solution.

The old website solution should be prepared a bit:

1. Set up Storage and Cloud Service at your Azure account;
2. Install Azure SDK and if needed [Powershell Azure Cmdlets](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/wiki/Downloads) (before Azure SDK 2.0 they were not integrated into the SDK);
3. Add new project to the solution with the type `Cloud -> Azure Project`, but don't select roles on this step;
4. Right-click on roles and add from existing web project.

At this step you may deploy solution from Visual Studio's drop-down menus like "Publish..." or "Package...". But configure your role first.

To make the package be automatically deployed, just do the script, which is described [here](http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2013/01/23/windows-azure-4-deploying-via-powershell/). This is the most clean script, I've found, which is making Deployment procedure of any Azure SDK.

To make automatic project package, just run the following powershell script:

```
$project = resolve-path ".\..\relative\path\to\azure\deploy\project.ccproj"
Import-Module -Name ".\Invoke-MsBuild.psm1"
$buildSucceeded = Invoke-MsBuild -Path $project -P '/p:configuration=release /p:overwritereadonlyfiles=true /p:targetprofile="Cloud" /target:Clean;Publish'
if ($buildSucceeded)
{ Write-Host "Build completed successfully." }
else
{ Write-Host "Build failed. Check the build log file for errors." }
```

For this script, you will need [Invoke-MsBuild](http://invokemsbuild.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Is there a better way for this in 2019 ?

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible. If using Azure Websites, you can do a git-deploy, dropbox, etc. If Cloud Services (web role), you can build via visual studio (IDE or command line), then deploy the package with PowerShell.

**EDIT** Quick example using PowerShell, to create a cloud service locally (via [New-AzureServiceProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205199.aspx) and [Add-AzureWebRole(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205203.aspx)):

```
New-AzureServiceProject -ServiceName myservice
Add-AzureWebRole -Name MyWebRole
```

You can add your code to the created web role and use msbuild to build it (and [cspack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx) to package it). You can then deploy your built package with PowerShell, via [New-AzureDeployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152867.aspx):

```
New-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "mynewservice" -Slot "production -Package packagepath -Configuration configpath -Label "my service deployment"
```

Note that with the package and configuration paths, they can either be local or in a blob (and you'd need to upload them to blobs before calling `New-AzureDeployment`). Also look at [Publish-AzureServiceProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn205170.aspx).

**Note**: The Azure PowerShell cmdlet reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj152841.aspx). But... if you type `get-help *azure*` at the PS command line, you'll see the latest cmdlets, and you can then look at help for individual cmdlets).

Beyond that, I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. But I strongly suggest spending some time with the [command-line tools + documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/#cmd-line-tools), as well as running through a few basic tutorials on asp.net + Azure, such as [this one](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/) for Web Sites and [this one](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/) for Cloud Services (in particular, the intro video).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Azure already post a lot of information about creating projects in cloud. But through the links you've provided, there is no info about creating deployment packages to Azure Cloud Service.

Comment: Yes, there is info about creating deployment packages with PowerShell cmdlets. I've gone ahead and edited my answer to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've given you a great start, and answered your original question.  Please type `azure --help` in the CLI to see what the CLI can do for you, including `azure service --help`.

Comment: after googling a number of hours, this answer shed me the light